# Fixing Columns in igGrid should show only single 'Add New Row' button for entire row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am very new in "infragistics" "igGrid" control.

The issue I am facing here is, when updating is enabled in combination with Column Fixing, there are two separate 'Add new row' buttons showing, one for the Fixed Columns area and one for the Non-Fixed Columns area, respectively.

[image]

I want that **only single 'Add new row' buttons should come i.e**, only Fixed Column(left side) 'Add New row' button should show, upon clicking it, user can able to add a new row.

Also, please let me know Is this a default setting of igGrid to show each time 'Add New Row' button for each Fixed Column area ?

Is there any property I can set in HTML code rather then writing some JavaScript function, to solve the issue I am facing ?

**Solution I tried:** Below is the .xml file of sample/test HTML code of igGrid (Could not post the original HTML code). I tried to set the 2 properties:

HasAddRowFeature="False"
AllowAddNewRow="Disable"
in 2nd column which is set 'Isfixed', but its not giving the desired output.

```
<Index ID="_Index" PrimaryKeyColumn ="RECORD_ID"  Width="1000px" HasAddRowFeature="True" HasDeleteRowFeature="True">

    <Column  Key="RECORD_ID" Text="" DataType="string" Width="0px" IsHidden="true" IsReadonly="true" />

    <Column  Key="Description" Text="Sample A" DataType="string" Width="150px" IsFixed="true" HasAddRowFeature="False" AllowAddNewRow="Disable" />

    <Column  Key="pqr" Text="Sample B" DataType="Object_List" ComboDataKey="ID" ComboTextKey="NAME" Width="150px" IsFixed="true"  />
    <Column  Key="abc" Text="Sample C" DataType="number" Width="100px" />
    <Column  Key="xyz" Text="Sample D" DataType="number" Width="100px"/>

</Index>
```

Please suggest some solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The screenshot that you've provided shows an igGrid, but the code provided seems like ASP.NET Web Forms configuration. This code is not applicable to the igGrid, so could you update the question with the igGrid configuration that you have? The reason to have two buttons is that the fixed column area may be too small to fit the add row button inside. You can try hiding the right button with CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The reason to have two buttons in igGrid when using **IsFixed** is that, it separates the igGrid into 2 sections, 1 with 'fixed column area' and other with 'non fixed column area'. Please let me know how to hide the non fixed column area 'Add New row' button in igGrid using CSS, so that it shall work as per the need ? please reply

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the second addRow button with the following code after initializing the `igGrid`:

```
$("#gridid .ui-iggrid-addrow:eq(2) span").hide();
```

I would suggest updating the code in your question as the code you've posted is not for the `igGrid`.